# move file to folder with the same name in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new in matlab and I have some problem in moving file
I have a list of files and I want to move them in folders with the same name%for example 1.txt ---> to folder 1
I have checked some codes but I have problems with the movefile command
Thank you in advance

```
%load and save only txt files
%just the files in struct
ls_al = dir;
justfiles = ls_al(~[ls_al.isdir]); %only for files
%save only folders by removing . and ..
%folders in cell
d = dir(pwd);
isub = [d(:).isdir]; %# returns logical vector
nameFolds = {d(isub).name}';
nameFolds(ismember(nameFolds,{'.','..'})) = [];
% move file to folder
for i=1:numel(justfiles)
filename=fullfile(justfiles.name(i));
foldername=fullfile(nameFolds(i));
movefile(filename,foldername);
end

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

> ??? Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed
>   by more reference blocks is an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your loop - you are indeding the `justfiles` variiable wrong:

```
filename=fullfile(justfiles.name(i));
```

this should be:

```
filename=justfiles(i).name;
```

Your use of fullfile here is incorrect as well - so I removed it.   You are only passing in a single argument - see `help fullfile` for correct usage of providing folder(s) and filename.

Comment: Though likely not needed in this context, passing a single argument to `fullfile` can be useful because the function corrects file separators (e.g. `fullfile('C:\test/test\test.exe')` returns a path appropriate for the file system). Granted, it's fixing an issue that shouldn't have happened in the first place, but it's a nice application.